# How to save mongoose model with several updates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am creating an API method which handles transfer of money from one account to the other. From the post request I get the account IDs for the transfer, the transfer amount, and references(for creating transactions).

Here’s my schema which is using the embedded document approach.

```
const AccountSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    number: {type: Number, index: true, unique: true, required: true},
    type: {type: String, required: true},
    status: {type: String, required: true},
    balance: {type: Number, required: true},
    user: {type: String, required: true},
    transactions: [TransactionSchema]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

- First I want to find the two accounts “from_account” and “to_account” and store their IDs.
- Next I create Transaction objects for both accounts “from_transaction” and “to_transaction”.
- Next I push the transaction objects into the transaction field in the account array for each account.
- Next I update the new balance of the accounts with the new balances per the transaction amount.
- Next I save.

When I do all this I it works fine except when I save which crashes the app.

What am I doing wrong and is this even the right approach?

Here’s my code. PS: I am calling save multiple times which is wrong but calling it once also produces and error saying accounts.save() isn’t a function. I am also treating each account separately because different things need to happen to each of them.

```
exports.interAccountTransfer = (req, res) => {

    const logged_in_user = req.decoded;
    const { from_account, to_account, transfer_amount, from_ref, to_ref } = req.body;

    var from_transaction = new Transaction({
        name: 'INT.D',
        amount: -transfer_amount,
        reference: from_ref,
        type: 'debit'
    });

    var to_transaction = new Transaction({
        name: 'INT.C',
        amount: transfer_amount,
        reference: to_ref,
        type: 'credit'
    }); 

    Account.find({_id: {$in: [from_account, to_account] }, user: logged_in_user.user_id }, (err, accounts) => {

        if (!accounts) return res.status(404).send({ message: `Accounts not found!` });
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: `Opps something went wrong!` });

        accounts[0].transactions.push(from_transaction);
        accounts[1].transactions.push(to_transaction);

        accounts[0].balance = accounts[0].balance - transfer_amount;
        accounts[1].balance = accounts[1].balance + parseInt(transfer_amount);


        accounts[0].save((err) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send({ message: `Opps something went wrong!` });
            }

            res.status(200).send({ message: `Transaction added successfully!` });
        });

        accounts[1].save((err) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send({ message: `Opps something went wrong!` });
            }

            res.status(200).send({ message: `Transaction added successfully!` });
        });

        res.send(accounts);  

    });

}
```

I want to update both accounts in the array with new balances and transaction objects.

Comment: When your app crashes, what is the `error` it is displaying? Also, you can not send multiple responses to the server from one method. It will just carry the first response.

Comment: Hi @ShamsNahid I get the following error but it saves correctly and everything works as expected except it crashes.

POST /api/accounts/transfer 200 36.378 ms - 2659
events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:482:11)

Answer (score 0):

look you wrote twice after each save

```
   res.status(200).send({ message: `Transaction added successfully!` });
```

you can send the res after you save both of them

```
   accounts[0].save((err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send({ message: `Opps something went wrong!` 
            });
        }    
    });

    accounts[1].save((err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send({ message: `Opps something went wrong!` 
            });
        }            
    });

    res.status(200).send({ message: `Transaction added successfully!`,
                          accounts: accounts });
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I will go with the solution provided above as it fixes a lot more. Appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code:

1.The `.find()` method always return an array, even if it find no match, it still return an empty array so `!accounts` will always be `false`.

2.You can not make sure that `accounts[0]` is from account and `accounts[1]` is to account.

3.You send response after each save. This cause the crash.

You can solve these problems by using two queries, one for from account, one for to account, use `async/await` and `try/catch` to avoid callback hell and send success response once after everything is finished.

```
exports.interAccountTransfer = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const logged_in_user = req.decoded;
    const { from_account, to_account, transfer_amount, from_ref, to_ref } = req.body;

    var from_transaction = new Transaction({
      name: 'INT.D',
      amount: -transfer_amount,
      reference: from_ref,
      type: 'debit'
    });

    var to_transaction = new Transaction({
      name: 'INT.C',
      amount: transfer_amount,
      reference: to_ref,
      type: 'credit'
    }); 

    var from = await Account.findOne({_id: from_account , user: logged_in_user.user_id });
    if (!from) return res.status(404).send({ message: `Accounts not found!` });
    var to = await Account.findOne({_id: to_account , user: logged_in_user.user_id });
    if (!to) return res.status(404).send({ message: `Accounts not found!` });

    from.transactions.push(from_transaction);
    to.transactions.push(to_transaction);

    from.balance = from.balance - transfer_amount;
    to.balance = to.balance + parseInt(transfer_amount);

    await from.save();
    await to.save();

    res.status(200).send({ message: `Transaction added successfully!` });
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: `Opps something went wrong!` });
  }
}
```

Comment: This works exactly like I wanted. Learnt something new. Appreciate this.